# How to fix Slow Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

have Intel Core i7 laptop with 8 GB ram. This is my first time using the Emulator, what are the best settings for the AVG? I want it to be fast.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried or searched for? See: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+emulator+performance&submit=search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the extra `Intel x86 Emulator Accelator (HAXM)` that comes with the Android SDK Manager. After installing it:

[image]

You can find it at:

```
.\android-sdks\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\IntelHaxm.exe
```

[image]

And as stated in the image:

> Intel HAXM requires an Intel processor with certain hardware features,
>   including Intel vertualization Technology (VT).

Usually, enabling VT is done from BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Architecture of Android Processors are of type ARM (RISC) not Intel(CISC) but you can mount large amount of power such larger clock rates and memory to emulate more faster, and finally it wouldn't be relative to power of your PC.
Another thing that may be useful for you is that, you can do debugging procedure without closing emulator each time it need to launch. the Emulator will consider changes to test application during debugging.